# caddy in docker reverse proxy to a tunnel to local machine not working

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, amazon-ec2, caddy

For development, a lot of platforms offer a webhook event but require HTTPS and a valid domain. A lot of people use ngrok, but I had an EC2 instance on hand and it allows me to get a non-randomized subdomain for the webhook.

I had the following working with `nginx`:

```
subdomain -> ec2 instance running nginx as a process -> tunnel -> local machine
```

The change is to move from `nginx` to `caddy` in a docker instance using `caddy-docker-proxy`:

```
subdomain -> docker/caddy-docker-proxy running on ec2 instance -> tunnel -> local machine
```

This is my caddy settings:

```
  caddy:
    image: lucaslorentz/caddy-docker-proxy:ci-alpine
    container_name: caddy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      - CADDY_INGRESS_NETWORKS=caddy
    networks:
      - caddy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - caddy_data:/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      caddy_0: dev.domain.com
      caddy_0.reverse_proxy: 172.17.0.1:9000
```

I can confirm that `caddy` gets the request from the subdomain based on the logs.
I can also confirm that if I `curl localhost:9000/test` from the EC2 instance, it works.

This means that there is a disconnect between the docker container running `caddy-docker-proxy` and the host machine/EC2 instance.

Here's the error log from Caddy:

```
{
  "level": "error",
  "ts": 1695592513.784038,
  "logger": "http.log.error",
  "msg": "dial tcp :9000: connect: connection refused",
  "request": {
    "remote_ip": "redacted",
    "remote_port": "60083",
    "client_ip": "redacted",
    "proto": "HTTP/2.0",
    "method": "GET",
    "host": "dev.domain.com",
    "uri": "/test",
    "headers": {
      "Sec-Fetch-User": [
        "?1"
      ],
      "Accept-Encoding": [
        "gzip, deflate, br"
      ],
      "Accept-Language": [
        "en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8"
      ],
      "Sec-Ch-Ua": [
        "\"Chromium\";v=\"116\", \"Not)A;Brand\";v=\"24\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"116\""
      ],
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": [
        "?0"
      ],
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": [
        "\"macOS\""
      ],
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": [
        "1"
      ],
      "User-Agent": [
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
      ],
      "Accept": [
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
      ],
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": [
        "none"
      ],
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": [
        "navigate"
      ],
      "Cache-Control": [
        "max-age=0"
      ],
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": [
        "document"
      ]
    },
    "tls": {
      "resumed": false,
      "version": 772,
      "cipher_suite": 4865,
      "proto": "h2",
      "server_name": "dev.domain.com"
    }
  },
  "duration": 0.00028104,
  "status": 502,
  "err_id": "ra595z5i9",
  "err_trace": "reverseproxy.statusError (reverseproxy.go:1248)"
}
```

I run my tunnel from my Macbook with this:

```
tunneldev() {
  emulate -LR bash;
  echo "Tunneling $1 on core server to $2 on localhost";
  ssh -R $1:localhost:$2 -N lab;
}

tunneldev 9000 3000
```

Feels like I just need one more setting to allow the docker container to properly send traffic through the tunnel but can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The connectivity issue you're facing is related to a bad combination of network interfaces.

```
                              172.17.0.1
      Docker container                        EC2 Machine
   ┌────────────────────┐        ┌──┐  ┌───────────────────────┐
   │                    │        │  │  │                       │
   │       Caddy        ├───────►│  ├──┼────► Nothing          │
   │                    │        │  │  │                       │
   └────────────────────┘        │  │  │                       │
                                 └──┘  │                       │
                                       │                       │
                                       │                       │         Dev Machine
                                 ┌──┐  │                       │     ┌─────────────────┐
                                 │  │  │      SSH tunnel       │     │                 │
                                 │  ├──┼───────────────────────┼────►│   Dev Server    │
                                 │  │  │                       │     │                 │
                                 │  │  │                       │     └─────────────────┘
                                 │  │  │    ┌──────────────┐   │
                                 │  │  │    │              │   │
                                 │  │◄─┼────┤     Curl     │   │
                                 │  │  │    │              │   │
                                 │  │  │    └──────────────┘   │
                                 │  │  │                       │
                                 └──┘  └───────────────────────┘

                               127.0.0.1
```

Your docker container is considered to be a different host than your EC2 instance. This is why in the Caddy configuration you targeted the host by using its IP on the docker subnet (`172.17.0.1`). Consequently, traffic going from the docker container to the host is entering the host through a docker-related network interface.

Your SSH `-R port:ip:port` reverse port forwarding command binds to the loopback interface of the host (`127.0.0.1`), both because you didn't specify anything else in the command and because your SSH server is probably not allowing anything else anyway.

Since your forwarded port is open on the loopback interface and not the docker-related network interface that the container sends traffic to, the docker container cannot connect to it.

To fix the port binding, you can tell SSH to open the port on a specific interface by using the longer `-R ip:port:ip:port` flag that lets you select the IP to bind on the host (the docker interface's IP `172.17.0.1` in this case). That way, the port will be open on the correct interface.

To allow this command to be executed, you will need to set the server's SSHd configuration option called `GatewayPorts` to `clientspecified`, instead of the default value `off` which limits you to the loopback interface.

Danger: Do **not** set `GatewayPorts` to `yes` which would expose forwarded ports on all interfaces, including the public internet-facing ones.

Your test command with curl will need to be adapted to use the IP instead of `localhost` (which resolves to `127.0.0.1`), since nothing will be listening on the loopback interface anymore.

Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/379344/selecting-interface-for-ssh-port-forwarding

Comment: thanks Joan, i forgot to update with an answer, but I did in fact change my SSHd config to `GatewayPorts=yes`, knowing the security risks. I'll be sure to change it to `clientspecified` now.

Do you know if there's a configuration that allows for the machine to listen on both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`? I have a few services running on this machine that can't go down if I need to debug an issue.

Comment: Listening on multiple IPs would be done by passing the ssh port forwarding arguments as many times as you need. Note that `localhost` is `127.0.0.1` but I assume you meant the host ip on the docker subnet. If you want to see forwards as they happen, you can put your ssh client in verbose mode.